# Continue painting form whilst running

Tags: c#, .net

I am  making an application that draws an image from a URL in C# .NET. Problem is, whilst this element is loading, it freezes the application and doesn't draw the rest of the form. Is there anyway to prevent this?

What I'm trying to say is there a way to continue running the rest of the program whilst performing this operation, like co-routines in other languages.

```
        WebRequest aReq = WebRequest.Create(avatarURL);
        WebResponse aRes = aReq.GetResponse();

        Image img = Image.FromStream(aRes.GetResponseStream());

        e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, 10, 10, 55, 55);
```

I tried using threading, but I can't get it to work my code  now looks like this:

```
        Thread drawavatar = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => drawAvatarDetails(e)));
        while (a_img != null)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(a_img, 10, 10, 55, 55);
        }
```

and inside drawAvatarDetaails I assign the global a_img to the image of the avatar

Comment: How is it loading? It's very difficult to optimize unseen code :)

Comment: can you share some code?

Comment: Added method that I'm using to get the image

Comment: Totally wrong aproach. Drawing inside a while loop will consume a lot CPU. Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use simply a `BackGroundWorker`. And do this inside the `DoWork` event. Ofcourse I advise keeping the image inside a global variable and draw it in Form's Paint (or control paint) event.

```
    BackgroundWorker bw;
    Image img;
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
        bw.RunWorkerAsync();
        this.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(Form1_Paint);
    }

    void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (img != null)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, 10, 10, 55, 55);
        }
    }

    void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        WebRequest aReq = WebRequest.Create(avatarURL);
        WebResponse aRes = aReq.GetResponse();
        img = Image.FromStream(aRes.GetResponseStream());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you access user controls in other than main UI thread, you would get `cross thread operation not valid` exception. Therefore if you are using .Net 4.5 I would recommend to use [async/await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx)

```
async void Draw(string avatarURL)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    Image img = Image.FromStream(await client.GetStreamAsync(avatarURL));

    // Your drawing code
    // for ex, this.BackgroundImage = img;

}
```